# Android: Contact Picker Intent | Cannot instantiate the type Uri

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to pick contacts with phone number only.And I am following [this code](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
...
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, new Uri("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

But unfortunately, its showing an error: `Cannot instantiate the type Uri`

Actually I have another working code which is working perfectly, but crashes on selecting Email contacts. I need only phone numbers.

```
Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intentContact.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);
```

and at `onReceive()`, this method is called

```
public void getContactInfo(Intent intent) {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    cursor = cr.query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        if (Integer
                .parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }
            phones.close();
        } else {
            snipp.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "No Number",
                    "Cannot read number", false);
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me:

```
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI );
    pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

**Edit:**

Your `onActivityResult()` should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent ) {

    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, intent );
    if ( requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST ) {

        if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
                Uri pickedPhoneNumber = intent.getData();
                // handle the picked phone number in here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what line of code is causing this exception? can you paste the full stack in the question?  are you defining your onActivityResult()?

Comment: Fixed. :)
It was a simple fix.. actually my mistake ..thanks for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 5):

Use Uri.parse() instead. You can't instsntiate a Uri directly