# Android Intent to pick contact from default Contact Address book

Tags: android, android-contacts

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

I saw the intent above is only allowed to pick the contacts but I need to pick call logs, favorite, contact just like Android OS Contact Book , How should i achieve this ?

Is there any Intent which allows this or do we need to code it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752388/android-contact-picker-intent-cannot-instantiate-the-type-uri. this is for contacts

Comment: It display all the contact in above link.. thanks I need contact list,call logs,groups as in android OS

Comment: you can get call log seperately. i am not sure how to qyeru all of them like android os. but seperately yes

Comment: Separately its possible , i was just searching is there any intent which gets all these at one side

Comment: you will have to design your own ui query all of them and set the tabs and contents to show exactly like what you mentioned. I am not aware of any such intent.