# Opening default people app with the phone filled

Tags: android

In my application, , I would like to click "Add Contact", called the default contacts(or people) app already filled with some fields, for example phone.

I know the default sms app and hangouts for example do this.

Comment: Maybe you can try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12752657/4319701 ?

Comment: In this post he is retrieving the contact, I would like to open the contacts app with the phone filled

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278587/insert-a-new-contact-intent ?