# Android. Use the SMS default interface to get the content in my app(to send it later). Delay SMS. It's possible?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, alarm, smsmanager

I have a scenario in mind and I don't know if it's possible:

1. Open the SMS interface from my app.(I can make this part)
2. Use the interface to write the message and search the contact(s).
3. When send button is pressed I want to store the information in my app and send it later.(I don't know if this is possible, if it is please give me some help)

Comment: If by "SMS interface", you mean an SMS app other than your own app, then no, this isn't really possible.

Comment: By SMS interface I meant to say the result obtain after executing:

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
startActivity(it);

Comment: Maybe there is a solution in the inverse sense... I felt that "it's a long shot" but 
it deserved to wonder

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the inverse sense", but sending an SMS like that is opening another app, which you don't really have any control over. If you need to delay the send, then just use `SmsManager`, like you were in your previous question.

Comment: If you're just trying to use the default SMS app for the Contacts feature, it's not that difficult to implement yourself. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752388/android-contact-picker-intent-cannot-instantiate-the-type-uri), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830184/in-android-how-to-pick-a-contact-and-display-it-on-my-app).

Comment: Thank you! Than I'll post a new question about how to make a simple browser for contacts.

Comment: No, you don't have to create your own Contacts browser. You can open the device's Contact list with an `Intent`. Please refer to the links in my previous comment.

Comment: Please, can you elaborate this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752388/android-contact-picker-intent-cannot-instantiate-the-type-uri)? I need more context to understand how it works. For example onActivityResult method is override but I don't know in witch class it's implemented and witch is the superclass. I know this may require a little bit of effort ...

Comment: The super class is `Activity`. Most SMS apps call the subclass something like `ComposeActivity`. In that, you would have a `Button` with an `OnClickListener` that calls the `pickContact()` method from the accepted answer. In that same `ComposeActivity`, you would override `onActivityResult()` as shown, to get the selected contact data from the list after the user picks one.

Comment: Please, can you help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810318/android-open-the-devices-contact-list-with-an-intent-not-working-unable-to-in)?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds possible to me.  You probably want the SMSManager to send a text... [source](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/telephony/smsmanager/android-how-to-send-sms-message/)

```
// Simplified...
String phoneNo = "8675309";
String sms = "Beni, I've got your number";

try {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Regarding searching the contacts and sending the text at a later time, it would be helpful if you could provide more specifics.

1. How will your app search the contacts?  Display a full list for them to pick from?  Allow them to enter text to match against the contact's name?
2. When you say "Send it later", what are your constraints for later?

For example, you could simply bring up their phone's contact viewer, and let them choose...

Comment: I knew about this... I want to use the system's sms app because it already had browsing contacts implemented so I shouldn't hardcod the phone numbers or to make a complicated browser for contacts...

Comment: Ah, you want to use the default SMS client to let the user create the message, choose the contact, but when they click "Send", have the SMS client return the message to your app so that you can send it at some future point in time?

No idea if it's possible or not, but I'd recommend writing your own interface, and just launch an intent to allow the user to select the contact.